# How to keep the source directory structure inside the output directory?

Tags: webpack

Using a `webpack.config.js` file like this:

```
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        main: 'src/js/main.js', 
    },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: '[name].js',
        publicPath: 'dist'
    }
}
```

Will lead to all the output files being placed in `/dist` without any directory structure. Please note that in my entry file i have the structure `src/js/main.js`. Is there a way to keep that structure in the output, resulting in `dist/js/main.js` rather than just `dist/main.js`?

PS: I want a solution that is dynamic as i will use multiple entry points.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to do either of these:

```
path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist/js'),
```

or

```
filename: 'js/[name].js',
```

Also, you aren't **required** to use `[name]`, you can just name the output file whatever you want (since you only have one entry point).

Comment: I edited my question. I want the solution to be dynamic as i will use multiple entry points. I'm sorry for not having clarified that when i asked.

Comment: My suggestion would be not to worry about making the `dist/` match `src/` because your `dist/main.js` is going to be an accumulation of all the files that it imports/requires, so it isn't going to match the file contents anyway. What I've done in other projects is change the key of the `entry` to contain any output path I wanted. For instance `entry: { 'some/path/main': 'src/js/main.js' }`  ... it's not as pretty, or dynamic, but it's effective.

Comment: I think that should do the job. Thank you!